# Unexpected performance of .at

Tags: python-3.x, performance, dataframe, indexing

Having observed these codes, we can clearly see that `.at` is quite faster than normal assignment.

```
aaa = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1],'b':[2],'c':[3]})
%timeit aaa['d']=5
>>90.6 µs ± 1.73 µs per loop

aab = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1],'b':[2],'c':[3]})
%timeit aab.at[aab.index[-1],'d'] = 5
>>8.73 µs ± 1.03 µs per loop
```

But when the same operation is replicated inside a function, It was observed that `.at` is slower than the normal assignment. Function for normal assignment:

```
def pred_norm(newpoint):
    [i for i in range(70000)]
    i= newpoint.columns[0]
    j= newpoint.columns[1]
    out_date = pd.to_datetime('nat')
    newpoint[i+'_Bing'] = 2
    newpoint[i+'_Joey'] = 13
    newpoint[i+'_Phoebs'] = 0.0
    newpoint[i+'_Ross'] = 0.28394
    newpoint[i+'_Rach'] = out_date
    newpoint[i+'_Mon'] = [{}]
    return(newpoint.reset_index(drop=True))
```

And the Time profile report is as follows:

[image]

Function for .at assignment:

```
def pred_at(newpoint):
    [i for i in range(70000)]
    kpi= newpoint.columns[0]
    j= newpoint.columns[1]
    out_date = pd.to_datetime('nat')
    newpoint.at[newpoint.index[-1],kpi+'_Bing'] = 2
    newpoint.at[newpoint.index[-1],kpi+'_Joey'] = 13
    newpoint.at[newpoint.index[-1],kpi+'_Phoebs'] = 0.0
    newpoint.at[newpoint.index[-1],kpi+'_Ross'] = 0.28394
    newpoint.at[newpoint.index[-1],kpi+'_Rach'] = out_date
    newpoint.at[newpoint.index[-1],kpi+'_Mon'] = [{}]
    return(newpoint.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Time profile report for `.at`:
[image]

We observe that the % of time spent on each of those `.at` assignment lines is higher. I verified this using `timeit` module as well.

```
# Data used for testing
data=pd.DataFrame({'Time':pd.to_datetime('2019-12-29',format='%Y-%m-%d'),'Sales':[26959.0]},index=[156])
```

Can somebody please explain this discrepancy?. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `timeit` module, it runs in iterations, so the overhead time to create a new column using .at is high whereas changing it is faster. That's why in multiple runs it takes lesser time than a normal assignment. When we run for a single iteration normal assignment is faster.

```
aaa = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1],'b':[2],'c':[3]})
%timeit -n 1 -r 1 aaa['d']=5
>>1.11 ms ± 0 ns per loop

aaa = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1],'b':[2],'c':[3]})
%timeit -n 1 -r 1 aaa.at[aaa.index[-1],'d'] = 5
>>3.62 ms ± 0 ns per loop
```